# FontAwesome Icons not working as links in HTML table

Tags: hyperlink, html-table, font-awesome

I have the following code that adds a font awesome icon to a table cell and wraps it in a link.

```
<table class="page_links" width="133" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                        <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                        <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                     </tr>
</table>
```

For some reason the links do not seem to be working. The cursor doesn't change icon when I hover over the cell indicating that there is a link present. Any ideas? Can this only be done with JavaScript or something?

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in css

> ```
> .page_links a{
> cursor:pointer;
> }
> ```

Comment: That doesn't work. My problem is that the icons do not seem to be being displayed as links in the first place.

Comment: Can you share fiddle or screenshot of it ?

Comment: Thanks I found the issue, I made an error with my footer